# Prove inequality: $|x-y|^r \le 2^r (x^r+y^r)$

Tags: inequality

This apparently holds by triangle inequality when $r>1$. But what about $0<r<1$? Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: As stated, your inequality doesn't always hold.  For example, with $r = 1$ and $x = y = -1$, the LHS becomes $0$ while the RHS becomes $-4$. However, if you impose appropriate conditions like $x, y \ge 0$, then I believe it'll be valid (and it can be proven using the triangle inequality hint given in the answer by [Servaes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/30382/servaes)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** By the triangle inequality $|x-y|\leq|x|+|y|$.

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to 
$$ \frac{|x - y|}{\sqrt[r]{|x|^r + |y|^r}} \leq 2.$$
By triangle inequality, the left hand side is bounded by 
$$ \frac{|x|}{\sqrt[r]{|x|^r + |y|^r}} + \frac{|y|}{\sqrt[r]{|x|^r + |y|^r}} \leq 1 + 1 = 2.$$